# You need to load kernel first - shows error in GRUB Mode

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel

Check out the screenshot. I initiated

initrd (hd0,msdos1)/initrd.img

[image]

and it occurs a warning message to load the kernel first.

I don't know how to load the kernel. I can't find it.

Also 
linux (hd0,msdos1)/vmlinuz root=dev/vda1 
shows the file is missing. But the file is already there in the root directory.

Comment: That should be `root=/dev/sda1` not what you have there!

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen I did change that but same error.

Comment: Do a `ls` and find where that file is.

Comment: See here for help: https://www.unix-ninja.com/p/Manually_booting_the_Linux_kernel_from_GRUB